# Should you change the current directory in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, jar, sh, working-directory

I've always mentally regarded the current directory as something for users, not scripts, since it is dependent on the user's location and can be different each time the script is executed.

So when I came across the Java jar utility's `-C` option I was a little puzzled.

---

For those who don't know the `-C` option is used before specifying a file/folder to include in a jar. Since the path to the file/folder is replicated in the jar, the `-C` option changes directories before including the file:

in other words:

```
jar -C flower lily.class
```

will make a jar containing the `lily.class` file, whereas:

```
jar flower/lily.class
```

will make a `flower` folder in the jar which contains `lily.class`

---

For a jar-ing script I'm making I want to use Bourne wild-cards `folder/*` but that would make using `-C` impossible since it only applies to the next immediate argument.

So the only way to use wild-cards is run from the current directory; but I still feel uneasy towards changing and using the current directory in a script.

Is there any downside to using the current directory in scripts? Is it frowned upon for some reason perhaps?

Comment: I don't see why the animosity, since the `cd` is local to the subprocess. Try this: `pwd; (cd ..; pwd); pwd` and see that as you exit the subshell (denoted by the parentheses), the current directory is back to where it started. Whatever the script does (unless you `source` it as opposed to executing it), it won't matter to the user.

Comment: It's okay, just put it back to where it was when you've finished.

Comment: @Amadan I realize that, but Gotos work too, yet they are frowned upon. I was wondering if there is something similar here with changing directories in scripts.

Comment: A `goto` was an abomination because it was unrestricted, way back when. You could jump from one subroutine to another, which made a mess of the environment and induced serious brain damage to anyone who had to read the code later. They are perfectly fine when used situationally. Interestingly, the situations where they are acceptable almost perfectly coincide with places you can use exceptions (which preserve hierarchical structure of the program). You can notice the same kind of thing going on here - a `cd` can't affect a superprocess, and subprocesses are your own responsibility.

Comment: There are other programs that support changing directories, `tar -C dirname` and `find -execdir` are two examples.

Comment: @Amadan actually I've found `goto`s amusing recently, since in assembly you essentially *only* have `goto` flow control since there are no loops.

Comment: Of course you will use `goto` if you don't have other flow control. In current languages, we do have `if`, `while`, `throw`, function execution (`gosub`, if you will) - and given that, I have everything I need. Same with global variables - if that's all you have, fine. If you have local variables, closures, object members, then global variables suddenly look like the ugly cousin with bad B.O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with changing the current directory from a shell script.  Certainly it won't cause anything bad to happen, if taken by itself.

In fact, I have a standard script that I use for starting up a Java-based server, and the very first line is:

```
cd `dirname $0`
```

This ensures that the rest of the commands in the script are executed in the directory that contains the script file itself (useful when a single machine is hosting multiple server instances), regardless of where the shell script was actually invoked from.  Without changing the current directory in the script, it would only work correctly if the user remember to manually `cd` into the corresponding directory before running the script.

In this case, performing the `cd` operation from within the script removes a manual step from the server startup/shutdown process, and makes things slightly less error-prone as a result.

So as with most things, there are legitimate uses for this sort of thing.  And I'm sure there are also some questionable ones, as well.  It really depends upon what's most appropriate for your specific use-case.  Which is something I can't really comment on...I always just let `maven` build my JAR's for me.

Comment: yep, `\`dirname $0\`` was what I used as well, I was wondering whether or not I **should**.

Comment: @Hawken: Please see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) regarding the location of a script.

Comment: @Hawken - The question of _should_ is really up to you.  There's nothing to prevent you from doing so, though there are some _very_ obscure caveats that may come up as per Dennis's link above.  You just have to decide if you're happy to live with those caveats or not.  Personally they don't bother me, as I'd _much_ rather have a self-contained server deployment than a bulletproof solution that won't break if someone `mv`'s the script out from under me as I'm running it.  If another sysadmin is `mv`'ing my stuff around, then I've got more serious problems to worry about anyways.